# Have a nice trip or enjoy your stay

Tags: phrase-usage

If you meet someone who is traveling in your country by chance
 and have a nice conversation, do you say 
"have a nice trip."
 or 
" enjoy your stay." 
when you finish your conversation ?
I assumed you say "have a nice trip" before someone goes on a trip , but is this correct?

Comment: Note that "enjoy your stay" is associated with, say, hotel clerks more than good friends.

Comment: OK, so  it's ok to say "enjoy your stay" ,because that's a tourist you've never met before,right?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether they are *coming to* your country, where you currently live, or if you are talking to them in *another* country and they are *going away* to your country.

"Have a nice trip" implies that they are traveling *away* from you to somewhere else.  For example, you could say:

> I hope you have a nice trip to Spain, I hear it's really nice this time of year.

However, this would be confusing if I am already *in* Spain.

> A: I hope you have a good trip to Spain!
>   B: Wait, don't you live in Madrid?
>   A: No, not any more. I'm in Paris now.

Instead if someone is already in your own country, it is *hospitable* to say something like, "Enjoy your stay (here)!" or "Enjoy your time (here)!"

Comment: The second example is a bit confusing, but in most cases I'm in a situation like the first one , so I'll say " enjoy your stay " , and thanks for telling me another good phrase " enjoy your time".!

Comment: @Kijitora "Coming" and "going" can be confusing in English.  See this for example: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/112873/how-do-you-use-come-and-go-and-how-different-are-they.  When you "go on a trip" it's a direction *away* from the point of view, so if I say "have a good trip" but I live in the place you're traveling *to*, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

In polite conversation, yes, both would be acceptable.

The one you choose depends on how much you know about the other's future plans.  If you know they are continuing their travels, use 'have a nice trip'.  Otherwise, 'enjoy your stay' work for most situations.

Comment: Thanks:)  " Enjoy your stay" seems to be a very useful phrase in such a situation.